# How to set IPN URL after payment completion in 2checkout payment gateway

Tags: notifications, 2checkout

I searched hard for any IPN URL setting. I tried the developer simulation for IPN. But when 2checkout in live mode then how to set IPN URL after payment completion in 2checkout payment gateway. For example setting in html form just like x_receipt_link_url parameter which is for redirecting after payment but this parameter I can not get message_type like ORDER_CREATED, RECURRING_STOP etc. Any other solution like setting in admin side of 2checkout account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your INS URL for each message type can be setup under the Notifications tab in your 2Checkout admin area.

[2Checkout INS Documentation](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/notifications/)

Feel free to [contact 2Checkout tech support](https://www.2checkout.com/contact/) for assistance with any questions that you have.

Comment: Thanks i will contact with 2checkout supports